# How to ignore methods when using JaCoCo with Gradle and Kotlin?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, jacoco

I'm trying to set up JaCoCo with Gradle and Kotlin and my problem is that I have a lot of `data class`es which have compiler-generated `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` methods.

I've read in the docs that with JaCoCo I can have **ignored** methods but seems like that the Gradle plugin for JaCoCo only supports **exclusion**s. How do I fix this?

I tried this:

```
test {
    jacoco {
        exclude("*equals", "*hashCode")
    }
}
```

but I can still see 0% next to those methods.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated for example in announcement of [JaCoCo version 0.8.1](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jacoco/qG0Mce7RiO4/axqZAP_GAgAJ): the only thing you need to do - is to make sure that Gradle uses correct JaCoCo version. All filters implemented so far in JaCoCo are enabled unconditionally and take place during generation of report. In the same announcement and in [announcement of 0.8.2](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jacoco/aMi1SkcfLZc/_UWgrC9xAQAJ) you can see that

> With Gradle JaCoCo Plugin you can select both runtime and version for "JaCoCoReport" task using "toolVersion" - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html

And that default version depends on version of Gradle - for example [Gradle 4.7 by default uses version JaCoCo 0.8.1](https://docs.gradle.org/4.7/release-notes.html#default-jacoco-version-upgraded-to-0.8.1), while according to [JaCoCo changelog](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/changes.html) filters for Kotlin were added in 0.8.2.

---

So given `src/main/kotlin/DataClass.kt`

```
data class DataClass(var x)
```

`src/test/kotlin/Tests.kt`

```
class Tests {
  @org.junit.Test
  fun test_data_class() {
    DataClass(42)
  }
}
```

and `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = "1.2.41"

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}

apply plugin: "kotlin"
apply plugin: "jacoco"

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
  testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
}

tasks["jacocoTestReport"].dependsOn("test")
```

After execution of `gradle jacocoTestReport` using Gradle 4.7 you'll see

[image]

And after addition of

```
jacoco {
  toolVersion = '0.8.2'
}
```

the same Gradle and the same command will produce

[image]

---

P.S. I believe that `exclude` in your attempt

> ```
> test {
>     jacoco {
>         exclude("*equals", "*hashCode")
>     }
> }
> ```

refers to [exclusion of tests from execution](https://docs.gradle.org/4.7/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:exclude(java.lang.Iterable)), because [`jacoco` property of `test`](https://docs.gradle.org/4.7/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:jacoco) has no `exclude` - as a proof addition of

```
test {
  jacoco {
    exclude("Tests.class")
  }
}
```

to the same above example leads to zero tests.